# Acessing public download folder with download manager

Tags: java, android, firebase, download

i'm trying to download some files from firebase so i created this methode

```
private void downloadFile(String url, String destination,String fileName,String fileExtension)
{
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,destination,fileName+"."+fileExtension);
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

but the files isn't saved in the public download folder it saved in Android/data/appPackageName/files/storage/emulated/0/Download

Comment: Yes that is path of `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()`. Use a different more apropiate destination. Android Studio will suggest some. Choose the right one.

Comment: try this `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);`